# AWS Route 53: How to migrate a hosted zone from one account to another completely?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have two AWS accounts old and new.

I have a hosted ZONE on old account under Route 53 service.

I want to migrate it completely from old to new.

How can I do it ? Are there any predefined steps for such case ?

Please note that the hosted zone is being used in a live environment. I can not risk too much trial and error.

Comment: Why not manually create the records, else use the CLI?

Comment: Duplicate all the records (if you have a lot, use the API) then cut over to the new set of nameservers.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) ("sed for JSON") to convert the JSON output of `list-resource-record-sets` to the JSON input to `change-resource-record-sets`:

```
jq '.ResourceRecordSets 
  |{"Changes":[.[] 
  |select(.Type!="SOA") 
  |select(.Type!="NS") 
  |{"Action":"CREATE","ResourceRecordSet":.}]}'
```

This assumes you have already created the new hosted zone and that it is empty except for the `SOA` and `NS` records, which are therefore removed from the JSON file. (The line breaks are for readability; remove them to use the command.)

Answer (score 3):

This is trivial using the AWS CLI. First, get your hosted zone id:

```
$ aws route53 list-hosted-zones
{
    "HostedZones": [
         {
            "ResourceRecordSetCount": 15,
            "CallerReference": "A5A5A3AF-C239-39FB-DA4C-556BA9FD1767",
            "Config": {},
            "Id": "/hostedzone/Z1LVCQHJBJUCM5",
            "Name": "example.com."
        }
    ]
}
```

Then export the list of resources for that hosted zone:

```
$ aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone Z1LVCQHJBJUCM5
```

This will output a json blob of your records, which is very close to the format you'll need to re-import into the new zone, using the [`change-resource-record-sets`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html) command. Look through the documentation, examining the output format of `list-resource-record-sets` and the input format of `change-resource-record-sets` and it'll be clear what you need to do to import the records.

Once you have the records in place in the new zone, update your domain registrar to point to the set of Route53 nameservers for this zone.

Comment: Don't forget to update your registrar to complete the migration.

Step 5. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html

Comment: @imperalix Great point...edited as such.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a tool for this very problem.

https://github.com/andersjanmyr/route53copy

`$ route53copy
Usage: route53copy-linux <source_profile> <dest_profile> <domain>`

Answer (score 1):

A more updated answer. This is how I did it without external tools, just `aws` and a text editor.

First, according to [the CLI docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/create-hosted-zone.html): "*You **can't create** a hosted zone for a top-level domain (TLD) such as .com*" (or .org, .net etc.).

No biggie, go to the new account and create it manually, it's a concise thing:

[image]

Now that you have created a Hosted Zone, it's just a matter of fill it with records. So, get the records from the old account into a .json file for comfort:

```
$ aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone YOURHOSTZONEID --output json --profile account1 > records.json
```

You can get your YOURHOSTZONEID directly from the web console ("Hosted Zone ID" column in the previous image) or from your terminal: `$ aws route53 list-hosted-zones --profile account1`.

This `--profile account1` option is a  reference to the potentially multiple account configuration, originally stored in ~/.aws folder: files `config` and `credentials`. If you haven't configured them, you can edit the two files manually (adding all the accounts you want, including IAMs), but I recommend using `$ aws configure` explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html).

Now, when you use any aws command with a particular `--profile`, it will know what account you want to use.

The JSON we downloaded needs to be "adapted" to the actual JSON structure the `change-resource-record-sets` is expecting. For some reason, using the `--generate-cli-skeleton` should give you an exemplar to know what structure is expected. Still, in this case, it's different (and therefore wrong), don't know why, from what is expected (which you can [find here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html#options), first JSON example). This is a reduced and a bit concealed version, but with the right structure:

```
{
  "Comment": "",
  "Changes": [
    {
      "Action": "UPSERT",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "domain.org.",
        "Type": "A",
        "TTL": 300,
        "ResourceRecords": [
          {
            "Value": "11.111.111.111"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Action": "UPSERT",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "domain.org.",
        "Type": "MX",
        "TTL": 300,
        "ResourceRecords": [
          {
            "Value": "20 mx1.domain.com"
          },
          {
            "Value": "10 mx2.domain.com"
          },
          {
            "Value": "50 mx3.domain.com"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Action": "UPSERT",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "domain.org.",
        "Type": "NS",
        "TTL": 172800,
        "ResourceRecords": [
          {
            "Value": "number.awsdns-28.com."
          },
          {
            "Value": "number.awsdns-23.org."
          },
          {
            "Value": "number.awsdns-31.co.uk."
          },
          {
            "Value": "number.awsdns-49.net."
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, you have to insert each `ResourceRecordSets`' JSON from the account1 into each object, starting with `"Action"` in the JSON to send to the account2. Then we send it like so:

```
$ aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z3IVB20ZV4QU6O --change-batch file://adaptedfile.json --profile account2
```

Notice that files in aws CLI are referenced with the **file:// schema**.

Bonus tip: if you encounter errors, you can add a `--debug` option that may help you figure out what's wrong.